# Change data directory of Docker

Tags: server, lxc, docker

How can I change the data directory of Docker where docker save the container (or where lxc save the container)?
I have in my server a ssd and a hard drive ant I want that the container will be save on the hard drive.
Thanks

Comment: An easy and simple solution here that worked for me - https://www.guguweb.com/2019/02/07/how-to-move-docker-data-directory-to-another-location-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 13):

I believe that in [this guide](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169) you'll have a good explanation.

> You can change Docker's storage base directory (where container and images go) using the -g option when starting the Docker daemon.
>
> Ubuntu/Debian: edit your `/etc/default/docker` file with the `-g` option: `DOCKER_OPTS="-dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4 -g /mnt"`
>
> Fedora/Centos: edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker`, and add the `-g` option in the other_args variable: ex. `other_args="-g /var/lib/testdir"`. If there's more than one option, make sure you enclose them in " ". After a restart, (service docker restart) Docker should use the new directory.
>
> Using a symlink is another method to change image storage.
>
> Caution - These steps depend on your current /var/lib/docker being an actual directory (not a symlink to another location).
>
> 1) Stop docker: `service docker stop`. Verify no docker process is running ps faux
>
> 2) Double check docker really isn't running. Take a look at the current docker directory: ls `/var/lib/docker/`
>
> 2b) Make a backup - `tar -zcC /var/lib docker > /mnt/pd0/var_lib_docker-backup-$(date +%s).tar.gz`
>
> 3) Move the `/var/lib/docker` directory to your new partition: `mv /var/lib/docker /mnt/pd0/docker`
>
> 4) Make a symlink: `ln -s /mnt/pd0/docker /var/lib/docker`
>
> 5) Take a peek at the directory structure to make sure it looks like it did before the mv: `ls /var/lib/docker/` (note the trailing slash to
>
> 6) Start docker back up `service docker start`
>
> 7) restart your containersresolve the symlink)

Comment: what is the reason for 4)? Is it needed? In my case, I would like to have docker files to be on a  mounted RAID, and not on the boot partition.

Answer (score 13):

In more recent Docker versions on Ubuntu you will edit `/etc/default/daemon.json` like so:

```
{
  "data-root": "/new/location"
}
```

Comment: ```$ ls /etc/default/daemon.json
ls: cannot access '/etc/default/daemon.json': No such file or directory```

Comment: I had to create the file and, doing that, it works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @MattK's answer:

The [Docker documentation on controlling the Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options) suggests that platform independent way to do this is:

edit the /etc/docker/daemon.json file (create it if it doesn't already exist) to contain the line

```
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data",
    (...)
}
```

where `/mnt/docker-data` is the directory where you want the docker images and containers to live.

Then

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

You can check whether it worked by running

```
docker info
```

and look for the contents of the line that start with `Docker Root Dir:`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50217666/2209313 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452368/36043.

Note that https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061807/2209313 suggests that if you installed Docker via Snap, you should find your `daemon.json` file in `/var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json`.

Comment: ```$ ls /etc/docker/daemon.json
ls: cannot access '/etc/docker/daemon.json': No such file or directory```

Comment: @LuísdeSousa perhaps some of the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689271/wheres-dockers-daemon-json-missing would help you find or create your daemon.json file if it is not in the default location specified by the Docker documentation I pointed to

Answer (score 2):

To change the `data` directory in `docker` it needs to be run with the option `-g /my/data`. In my `/etc/default/docker` I set:

`DOCKER_OPTS="-g /srv/docker"`

See also [my notes here](http://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/debian/37-docker-1-7-on-debian-ubuntu).

To change the `data` directory in `lxc` I put in `/etc/lxc/lxc.conf`:

`lxc.lxcpath = /srv/lxc`

Comment: At the top of that file there is this warning: "THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD"

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Docker 1.13.0.

From the Release Notes:

```
- New
The storage location of the Linux volume can now be moved
```

Answer (score 0):

After having upvoted the given answers by Stuart and Conrado, I realized it didn't work, and my system partition went full again.

I actually had to edit the systemd unit file, like described in the following blog article: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux.

All together, here are the steps :

1. `sudo systemctl stop docker docker.socket`
2. `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/docker.service`
3. Change the line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` into `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /new/path/docker -H fd://` and save the file
4. `sudo mkdir -p /new/path/docker`
5. `sudo rsync -aqxP /var/lib/docker/ /new/path/docker`
6. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
7. `sudo systemctl start docker`

Now, my system partition remain slim, the `/var/lib/docker` folder is not re-created.

---

**Update following Dan's comment**

As Dan stated, updating the Docker packages overrides my update and makes Docker using the default path again.

Following his advice, here is how to **properly** override the default storage path :

1. `sudo systemctl edit docker`
2. The above command creates an empty file where you need to copy/past the following :

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /new/path/docker -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

3. `systemctl status docker.service` will ensure all is fine with the override of the Docker configuration
4. `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Now Docker is using the new place, and you can update the Docker packages without loosing your configuration.

*Note : The reason for the empty `ExecStart=` is to clear the value from the original file, and the second one fills it again.*

Comment: The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options) says that it should work when updating the `daemon.json` file. Have you restarted docker after changing the config? Otherwise, I wouldn't recommend editing Docker's main `systemd` file, instead, you should use `sudo systemctl edit docker` and override the lines that you want to be overridden. Otherwise, you may lose your changes during an upgrade.

Comment: Yep, I did restart the docker service, but I have updated the `/etc/default/docker` file instead since with Debian like distribution it should be done here, like it is said in the Conrado's answer. Anyway, thank you for sharing the `sudo systemctl edit docker` command !